# Car insurance for the summer in Canada

Tags: canada, car, car-insurance

We're thinking about buying a car in Nova Scotia, Canada while we are here for the summer. We are residents of Ontario. We don't really want to keep the car past our time here. The question is how do we insure the car?

On calling to a insurance broker, they said they don't do anything less then a year and suggested for us to find a short term insurance on the internet. We've found nothing so far.

How should we proceed?

Comment: Do you have insurance in Ontario?

Comment: Nope, no insurance currently

Answer (score 4):

Call another insurance agent, one who is not affiliated with a specific insurance company. If that doesn't work, call another one.

I have insured cars for a weekend, and a diamond for a day. There is always someone willing to sell insurance. However, it definitely helps to have an existing relationship with a third party insurance vendor.

*Edit to add:* You may also consider reading the fine print on the cancellation policies of a longer policy. Figure out what the penalty would be after cancelling a year long policy after 3 months. It may very well be nothing.

Answer (score 1):

For us, in the end, the answer was to go with Strum Insurance. They insured us with Pafco.

Other insurance companies, like TD were a no go, because they required us to get a NS driver's license within a month.